# I can't pacify a Wild Mongrel?

Tags: fallout-4

I have the Wasteland Whisperer perk, and I went to try and pacify a wild mongrel, but when I got close and ADS, I didn't get any option to pacify it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

According to the wikia page for [Wasteland Whisperer](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Wasteland_Whisperer), mongrels are not listed to be pacified with this perk. You will instead need the perk [Animal Friend](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Animal_Friend).